# Environment variable in Driver path in odbc.ini

Tags: odbc, pyodbc

Can environment variable be part of the Driver path specified inside odbc.ini file ?
something like below.

[SYB]
Driver = ${DRIVER_PATH}/libsybdrvodb.so

odbc driver installation path is different across the environments and i do not want to hard code the absolute path which will require maintaining more than one odbc.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an odbc.ini file where anything like that was done. However, you could use an environment variable to help construct a (DSN-less) connection string that you pass to pyodbc, e.g.,

```py
conn_str = (
    f"DRIVER={os.getenv('MSODBCSQL_NAME')};"
    r"SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;"
    "DATABASE=myDb;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes"
)
print(conn_str)
# DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=myDb;Trusted_Connection=yes
```